# JasperPrint object in HTTP session

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

Many samples/tutorials/books recommend to keep JasperPrint object in the HttpSession to achieve:

- Render images in HTML report through ImageServlet
- Pagination of reports in web applications

But I am wondering if this is the best practice. Correct me, my guess is JasperPrint object is not a trivial object to keep in the session.

Any experiences or bench marking details on heap usages and how many concurrent report execution per node possible with jasperPrint in session will be grateful.

Are there any other alternatives to achieve this without keeping jasperPrint object in session?

We are using dynamicreports API with JSF frontend.

Answer (score 0):

what's the problem to keep it in memory?
If you don't need the object you can remove it with

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
            .getSessionMap()
            .remove("#{YourSessionBean}");
```

Comment: The jasperprint object contains the data of your entire report (effectively). Now you can imagine the problems with this especially in multi user scenario, where it will bloat JVM heap memory. Sure we can remove, but it will not solve the problem I mentioned above.